# How to recompile a directive upon inserting into DOM (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Okay, so I've created a directive let's say

```
<calendar></calendar>
```

It gets rendered as I expected so everything works fine. Now, my question is how to (re)render it when inserted into DOM? I don't want to use it on my page all the time, I just want to dynamically add it and render just when I need it to (it's a part of a module), let's say, ideally I want it to appear like

```
$("body").append("<calendar></calendar>")
```

How can I achieve this with angularjs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write below two lines wherever you want to inject your directive element to DOM, don't forget to add `$document` & `$compile` dependency wherever you use it.

```
var template = '<calender></calender>',
    body = $document.find('body');
body.append($compile(template)(scope));
```

Comment: So that's actually means creating another directive that will compile my directive? No, I would like to find a one line solution

Comment: @CarterăVeaceslav this code tells that, you can inject your `calender` directive by using the lines inside the directive link fucntion..

Comment: Why it's so complicated to achieve in angular? With "plain" jQuery I write $("#mySelector").myModuleName({ ...my parameters }) and I can easily render my custom modules where I want them and WHEN I want them...

Comment: yeah, so what's "customeDir" then? I need one directive - "calendar"

Comment: You can do the same thing from controller also..before doing this you need to add `$document`, `$compile` dependancy, no new directive is required.I don't know why you considering, adding one line as a big thing?

Comment: @CarterăVeaceslav you have many answer here you can accept one of them atleast?

Comment: I can't find a solution for this, at least not like I suppose to see it happen. May be that's because I expect something from angularjs it can't handle the way I would like it to handle, or may be because I did not understand yet how it works and what to expect from it. I'll pick up your answer as accepted. Anyway, thanks to all people involved.

Comment: @CarterăVeaceslav yes i think you are new to angular, that why you are thinking like this, you may add jsfiddle/plunkr with demonstration of you problem will help us to find out a better way, which you want.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved with angular element:

```
angular.element('body').append($compile("<calendar></calendar>")($scope));
```

Comment: I tried it directly from chrome console, it says "$compile is not defined". What I'm missing?

Comment: @CarterăVeaceslav  include the dependency `$compile` on in your directive function

Comment: Can't make it work, my directive is w_calendar.directive("wcalendar", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        templateUrl: "templates/w_calendar.html",
        replace: true
    };
});

Comment: $compile is not accessible from console, it is undefined

Comment: where is you `link: function(){}` from where you can do compile you element

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of actions is this:

1. Create DOM element or `angular.element` object:

   ```
   var calendar = angular.element('<calendar></calendar>'),
   ```
2. Pass it to `$compile` service. At this stage you need to provide necessary scope object:

   ```
   $compile(calendar)(scope);
   ```
3. Append `calendar` element to document:

   ```
   angular.element('body').append(calendar);
   ```

So all together it looks like:

```
var calendar = angular.element('<calendar></calendar>');
$compile(calendar)(scope);
angular.element('body').append(calendar);
```

Comment: (2) $compile is undefined

Comment: You need to inject it in your service/controller.

Comment: @dsfq Do you think playing with DOM using factory is good thing?

Comment: @pankajparkar Sometimes you have to. For example, take AngularUI modal services.

Comment: @dsfq Your very correct, Thanks for clearing my doubt

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $compile service to recompile it and use angular.element('body').append to append it to the page again. E.g.:

```
    var el = $compile( "<calendar></calendar>" )( $scope );
    angular.element('body').append( el );
```